# Best way to share data

Tags: android, sql, web-services, web-applications, desktop-application

I want to develop an android app, a desktop app and a web app which share the same data. For example one user can write data from the desktop and read the same data on the android app.

Which is the best solution to share data between them in terms of develop and performace too? SQL Server? Web services? From which data source Android reading faster?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database + web service.

If you need to store data, you will need a database. Depending on what data you have, for what you need it, and how you use it, you can use a relational database or a [NoSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) database.

Whatever database you use, don't expose it to the clients directly. Use an API in front of it. A [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) style API should do the trick. With time, the API will allow you to evolve the database independently of how you expose the data to your clients. If you have the web application and the database on the same server you might use the database directly in the web application and make a trade of between performance (by not having the API as a layer in front of the database) or a consistent API across clients. It really depends on what application you have and how important every millisecond is for accessing your data.